# Change specific npm packages to local path to test locally

Tags: javascript, npm, babeljs

I have a repository called "components", inside a lot of isolated components working with bit, but I want to test the components without publishing every time that I change something, so anyone know how to achieve this?

They are in the same directory and always will be, and I know that the pattern to create a component is "@bit/vitorbarbosa19.ziro/{ComponentName}", so something like if a package start with @bit I get from the "../components/{ComponentName}".

But I really do not know how to do this hahahahaha, anyone with an idea? A script using babel?

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-link it might be what your looking for!

Comment: Interesting, looking right now!